# align values in a matrix

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have a matrix like this:

```
\begin{matrix}
   value\_list:\quad[a_{1,1}, a_{3,2}, a_{3,3}] \\ 
 start\_positions:\quad[0,2] \\ 
 column\_indexes:\quad[1,2,3] \\
 perm\_vector:\quad[2,0]
\end{matrix}
```

[image]

is it possible to align these values so they look good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I prepare for your question which you delete few seconds before I succeed to publish it ...

One way is to use `matrix*` defined in the `mathtools` package. It enable to add align options:

```
\begin{matrix*}[<align>]
```

where for align you can use `r` for right and `l` for left align.

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{mathtools}


\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & 0 & 0         \\
0       & 0 & 0         \\
0       & 0 & a_{3,3}
\end{pmatrix}   
    \xrightarrow{\mathrm{CRS}}
\begin{pmatrix}
(a_{1,1},   & 1, & 1)\\
(a_{3,3},   & 3, & 3)
\end{pmatrix} 
    \xrightarrow{\text{JDS}}
\begin{pmatrix*}[l]
\text{value\_list:}         [a_{1,1}, a_{3,3}]    \\
\text{start\_position:}     [1,2,3]               \\
\text{column\_indexes:}     [1,3]                 \\
\text{perm\_vetor:} [1,2]
\end{pmatrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or just `matrix` as you ask in question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[ 
\begin{matrix*}[l]
\text{value\_list:}         [a_{1,1}, a_{3,2}, a_{3,3}]    \\
\text{start\_position:}     [1,2,3]               \\
\text{column\_indexes:}     [1,3]                 \\
\text{perm\_vetor:} [1,2]
\end{matrix*}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

or with separately aligned math terms:

```
\[ 
\begin{matrix*}[l]
\text{value\_list:}         &  [a_{1,1}, a_{3,2}, a_{3,3}]  \\
\text{start\_position:}     &  [1,2,3]                      \\
\text{column\_indexes:}     &  [1,3]                        \\
\text{perm\_vetor:}         &  [1,2]
\end{matrix*}
\]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to use `matrix`, but `tabular`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l >{$}l<{$} @{}}
value\_list:      & [a_{1,1}, a_{3,2}, a_{3,3}] \\ 
start\_positions: & [0,2] \\ 
column\_indexes:  & [1,2,3] \\
perm\_vector:     & [2,0]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can place it wherever you want, including a math display.

My impression is that the plural of “index” is “indices” (it's a Latin word).

[image]